# Bad input shape on sentiment analysis logistic regression

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'd like to predict the accuracy of a Sentiment Analysis model with Logistic Regression, but get the error: **bad input shape** (edited with inputs)

Data Frame:

```
df
sentence                | polarity_label
new release!            | positive
buy                     | neutral
least good-looking      | negative
```

Code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder                                                   
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer, 
ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS
# Define the set of stop words
my_stop_words = ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS
vect = CountVectorizer(max_features=5000,stop_words=my_stop_words)
vect.fit(df.sentence)
X = vect.transform(df.sentence)
y = df.polarity_label
encoder = OneHotEncoder()
encoder.fit_transform(y)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=123)
LogisticRegression(penalty='l2',C=1.0)

log_reg = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Error Message

````
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=['Neutral' 'Positive' 'Positive' ... 'Neutral' 'Neutral' 'Neutral'].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.```

How can I fix this?
````

Comment: I am not 100% sure about this, but try `log_reg = Logistic_Regression()` and then `log_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)`

Comment: sorry, but the problem persists, even with that revision..

Comment: Can you add the shape of x_train and y_train?

Comment: your `y` is being transformed into a vector, you probably want to keep this as a categorical value e.g. `0 or 1`

Comment: y_train.shape --> (14578,) 
X_train.shape --> (14578,385) @AniketBote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust your code like this for example:

```
y = df.polarity_label
```

Currenlty you are trying to transform your y into a vector with your CountVectorizer, which is trained on the sentence data.

So the CountVectorizer has this vocabulary (you can get it with `vect.get_feature_names()`):

> ['buy', 'good', 'looking', 'new', 'release']

and will transform some text, that contains these words into a vector.

But when you use this on your y, which has only the words `positive, neutral, negative`, it does not find any of its "known" words and therefore your y is empty.

If you inspect your y after that transformation, you can also see that it is empty:

```
<3x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: after `y = df.polarity_label`, do i need to make them dummy variables again? Just using the `y = df.polarity_label` works, but the accuracy is suspiciously high 99%.

Comment: Your original question was answered. Instead of editing it to show your new problem, just ask a new question. Also provide your data, because without it, its difficult to debug your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to convert your y labels into One hot encoding,
right now your label vector could be like this [0,1,0,0,1,0],
but for logistic regression you need to convert them into this form [[0,1],[1,0],[0,1],[0,1]], because in logistic regression we tend to calculate probability/likelihood for all the classes.

You can do so by using sklearn [onehotencoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html),

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder                                                   
encoder = OneHotEncoder()
encoder.fit_transform(y)
```

Comment: ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=['Neutral' 'Positive' 'Positive' ... 'Neutral' 'Neutral' 'Neutral'].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The y variable has three values: 'Positive','Neutral', 'Negative'

Comment: for three variables, there can be two possibilities of one hot encoding 1. [0,0],[1,0],[0,1]( here you have choose "drop first" attribute in which [0,0] is interpreted as [0,0,1]. if you keep the 'drop first' as False, you will get somethings like this [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [1,0,0].   after applying onehotencoding to your label vector "y", you will a 2D matrix of the form [ [0,0],[0,1],[0,0]......] of the shape (len(y),2).